# Weighted k-means in python

Tags: python, k-means

After reading this post here about duplicate values in k-means clustering, I realized I cannot simply use unique points for clustering.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152808/do-i-need-to-remove-duplicate-objects-for-cluster-analysis-of-objects

I have over 10000000 points, though only 8000 unique ones. Therefore, I initially thought that for speeding it up, I’d use unique points only. Seems like this is a bad idea.

To keep computational time down, this post suggests to add weights to each point. How can this be implemented  in python?

Comment: Please add what have you tried and what is the problem with implementing in python ?:

Answer (score 7):

Using K-Means package from Scikit library, clustering is performed for number of clusters as 11 here.
The array Y contains data that has been inserted as weights where as X has actual points that need to be clustered.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans  #For applying KMeans
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------##
#Starting k-means clustering


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=11, n_init=10, random_state=0, max_iter=1000)

#Running k-means clustering and enter the ‘X’ array as the input coordinates and ‘Y’ 
array as sample weights
wt_kmeansclus = kmeans.fit(X,sample_weight = Y)
predicted_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X, sample_weight = Y)

#Storing results obtained together with respective city-state labels
kmeans_results = 
pd.DataFrame({"label":data_label,"kmeans_cluster":predicted_kmeans+1})


#Printing count of points alloted to each cluster and then the cluster centers
print(kmeans_results.kmeans_cluster.value_counts())
```

Comment: So the `sample_weight` should have the same length  of X right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the post suggests to work with weighted average.

You can create a new dataset out of the old one, and the new dataset will have an extra attribute for each point, it's frequency (i.e it's weight).

Every time you calculate the new centroid for each cluster, take the weighted average of all points of that cluster (instead of calculating the simple mean of all points).

PS: Manipulating the dataset is dangerous. I'd parallelize the code if computational cost is a major factor.